# PERL DBI: Inserting From .pl into an Oracle DB a to_date function into a test variable

Tags: sql, perl, date, dbi

First a big thank you to all PERL specialist in this wonderful website; i'am learning so much.

I have a small "translation" issue;

my .pl script perform these task sequentially:

1. Read a .txt file (in real life a log)
2. a regex cleans and store in memory variables some info
3. while reading line by line it inserts into a Oracle table
4. Exit and disconnect when finish gracefully.

The Table has 8 columns and one of this store date and time of an event and the format that i declared into sql is:

```
DATETIME_EVENT VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL
```

you can clearly see where i am going in a bit....

so point 3 above execute this block:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO myTable(TIME_ISSUE,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
```

EXAMPLE INSERTED IS: 2014-09-19 00:03:58,562

Everything is smooth and fine , however I will perform set of queries later on; but I  will have to translate with to_date function in SQL to interpret  TIME_ISSUE column as datetime TYPE.

AS:

```
select to_date(SUBSTR(TIME_ISSUE,0,19) ,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) from myTable;
```

OUTPUT: 19/09/2014 23:59:56

If I create the table.column as datetime type how can i write the perl insert block above in order to insert a txt into datetime type?

I tried but is not working at all:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO REQUEST (TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DATETIME_EVENT ,0,19), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),LOG_LEVEL,LOGONID, CLIENTID, USERID,IPADDRESS,DURATION,CLASSMETHOD) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')
```

p.s.

you can assume that if i run the perl above i have previously created that column as this:

```
TIME_ISSUE   DATE DEFAULT NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also change the date format for the session.  This is useful, for example, in Perl DBI, where the to_date() function is not available:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

You can permanently set the default nls_date_format as well:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

In Perl DBI you can run these commands with the do() method:

```
$db->do("ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_dbi_interface1.htm
https://community.oracle.com/thread/682596?start=15&tstart=0

Comment: I've been searching for this answer for days and your comment here is the only one that actually addresses the problem. The Alter Session bit is genius! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 1):

CPAN has the [DateTime::Format::Oracle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::Oracle) and [DateTime::Format::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime::Format::DBI) modules for this.

Comment: Hi Rob, how this gets applied in my case, look like i should declare first ad date_time type in my pl scrpt?

Comment: Actually, this module might be better

http://search.cpan.org/~cfaerber/DateTime-Format-DBI-0.041/lib/DateTime/Format/DBI.pm

Beautiful code snippet right at the top.